# MongoDB Response Slower on Amazon EC2 Server Than Localhost

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm loading the same amount of data (~100kb) on both my local server and a test Amazon EC2 server, but the response is 2x slower on EC2. Both are running Apache 2 and MongoDB on the same machine. On my local server, the response is about 209ms versus approximately 455ms on EC2.

I've setup a simple query and AJAX call that grabs point data to display on the map based on the current viewport of the device.

How can I debug this issue? How can I make it as faster as my local server? I even tried experimenting with different types of instances to make sure the specs are the same, but no luck. I also realize it could be because of network latency.

Local computer specs:

1. Intel Core i5 @ 3.30GHz
2. 8GB RAM
3. 64-bit Windows 8

Amazon EC2 specs (m4.large):

1. 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon Haswell (2 vCPUs)
2. 8GB RAM
3. Amazon Linux

Answer (score 1):

A remote query to EC2 is unlikely to return the result of the AJAX query as fast as your local server because it has network latency, while your local server does not.  Measure the time in your AJAX handler from the start of the query to the point where it is ready to return data to get a meaningful baseline for comparison.

MongoDB is very sensitive to data being in RAM vs on disk.  Depending on how you configured your EC2 instance, and on your local hardware, chances are pretty good that your local hardware is faster.  EC2 instances can be configured to use SSD storage, and you can configure a guaranteed IOPS figure.

Is the 100KB the size of the result set, or the amount of data needed to form the result set?  If you process 4GB of data down to get a 100KB result set, there's a good chance that disk IO is involved.  If the amount of data you need to pull is small, repeat the test a few times to ensure data is entirely in RAM.

Finally, if both local and EC2 are pulling data from RAM, there's a good chance that your local CPU core is just faster than the EC2 CPU core, and that your RAM access is faster as well.  EC2 is designed to provide low-cost commodity hardware.  Developer setups are often much faster.

If you cannot account for the speed differences given the factors above, update your question with the time measurements that exclude network latency and provide more detailed specifications about your hardware.  Update the question to indicate whether the data you are retrieving from MongoDB should be entirely in RAM, given it's size and the amount of RAM on your instance.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. I've updated my question with some server specs. 100KB is the size of the result set. I'm seeing it on consistent based that EC2 is 2x slower. How do I know if the data is being pulled from RAM? How can I check that?

Comment: Monitor disk IO during your test.  If there is little to any IO, your working set is in RAM.  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/460/command-line-tool-on-ubuntu-server-to-see-disk-io-stats

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it!